# Smooth automorphism preserves the Kähler class?

Tags: surfaces, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $S\subset \mathbb {CP^3}$ be a Kähler surface, $[\omega]$ be the Kähler class. Let $f:S\to S$ be a smooth orientation preserving automorphism (in the category of smooth manifolds, i.e. not has to be holomorphic). Is it true that $f^*[\omega]=[\omega]$?

Comment: Consider the quadric $Q \subset \mathbb{CP}^{3}$, it is diffeomorphic to $S^{2} \times S^{2}$. Now, (unlike $\mathbb{CP}^{2}$)  $S^{2} \times S^{2}$ has an orientation reversing diffeomorphism $f$, constructed by reflecting one of the $S^{2}$ factors. It is not hard to see for the $S^{2}$ factor that gets reflected, which we denote $S$, we have $f^{*}([\omega])[S] = - \omega([S])$. So probably you should add the condition that it is orientation preserving.

Comment: @NickL Yes I edited the question. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: There is no reason at all this should be true. Here is a counterexample, but I imagine there are basically always counterexamples. Following as in Nick L's comment, the oriented automorphism group of $S^2 \times S^2$ acts transitively on the set $\{[x], [y], -[x], -[y]\}$, where $H^2(S^2 \times S^2;\Bbb Z) = \langle [x], [y]\rangle$, the classes corresponding to the two factors. There is no fixed class under this action except zero.

Comment: (The generators are "reflection in both factors" and "swap factors and reflect one".)

Comment: What *is* true is that if $S$ is a hypersurface of degree $d \geq 5$, then any smooth automorphism preserves the set $\{K_S, -K_S\}$ where $K_S$ is the canonical class. This is a theorem of Seiberg-Witten theory.

Comment: Also of interest: If X is a del Pezzo surface and $\omega_{1},\omega_{2}$ are any symplectic forms then there is an orientation preserving diffeo $f$ such that $f^{*}(\omega_{2}) = \omega_{1}$, this is proved in the section on del Pezzo surfaces in Deitmar Salamons paper https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/unique.pdf. This provides many more counterexamples because for the cubic surface has infinite ample cone.

Comment: Yeah I see. Thanks for all your comments, which are really helpful.

Comment: @MikeMiller Also it would be good if you can post the comments as an answer (if you want).